# how to display and style a list based on array

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I'm trying to display a html list based on array like this:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

I can do:

```
var arrayLength = fruits.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    console.log(fruits[i]);
}
```

but is there a way of checking for the first element and base on that can I add specyfic class to it like this?

```
<li class="className">Banana</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li>Apple</li>
<li>Mango</li>
```

Comment: do these *li* have any parent element?

Comment: What are you wanting to check the first element for, the text/fruit it contains? That it exists?

Comment: Judging by the given code, it doesn't display html list. It just `console.log` array values

Comment: `var arrayLength = fruits.length,li='';
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    li  +=  '<li' + (i==0 ? ' class="className"' : '') + '>' + fruits[i] + '</li>';
}`

Comment: So, do you want to create a list or do you want to style the output to the console?

Comment: yes, I do want to create a list where first <li> has a specific class

Comment: @PranavCBalan thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so thanks to @pranav-c-balan

```
var arrayLength = fruits.length,li=''; 
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) { 
li += '<li' + (i==0 ? ' class="className"' : '') + '>' + fruits[i] + '</li>'; 
}
```

this code did the trick, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var html = '<ul>';
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  html += '<li' + (fruits[i] === "Banana" ? ' class="hello"' : '') + '>' + fruits[i] + '</li>';
}
html += '</ul>';

console.log(html);
document.write(html)
```

```css
.hello {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you can do this:

```
$('li').first().addClass( "myclass");
```

You can use pure javascript but jquery is faster and shorter. You should try it.

Comment: it's not about "banana" it's about first item from array, so if I use different array I want do have the same effect - first item from array will have li with class

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in vanilla javascript:

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var fruits = ['Banana','Orange','Apple','Mango'];

var fruitBasket = document.createElement('ul');
body.appendChild(fruitBasket);

for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    var newFruit = document.createElement('li');
    var newFruitName = document.createTextNode(fruits[i]);
    newFruit.appendChild(newFruitName);
    fruitBasket.appendChild(newFruit);

    if (fruits[i] === 'Banana') {
        newFruit.classList.add('green-banana');
    }
}
```

```css
.green-banana {
color: rgb(0,255,15);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla js Solution

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var list = document.createElement('ul');

fruits.forEach(function(value, index) {
  var item = document.createElement('li');
  list.appendChild(item);
  item.innerHTML = value
  if (index == 0) {
    item.className += "myClass";
  }
});
document.body.appendChild(list);
```

```css
.myClass{
  color:red;
  }
```

Jquery Solution create list based on the array

```js
 var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
  
  var list = $("<ul>");
  
  $(fruits).each(function(index,value){
    var item = $("<li>").html(value);
    if (index == 0 ) { item.addClass("myClass");}
    list.append(item);
  });
  $("body").append(list);
```

```css
.myClass{
  color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Jquery Solution for existing list

```js
 $("ul#myList li").each(function(index,value){
    if (index == 0 ) { $(this).addClass("myClass");}
  })
```

```css
.myClass{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
      <li>Banana</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li>Apple</li>
<li>Mango</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's play a recursive game...

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"],
    result = makeList("",fruits);

function makeList(h,a){
  return a.length ? makeList(a.length > 1 ? '<li>' + a.pop() + '</li>' + h
                                          : '<li class="'+a[0]+'Class">' + a.pop() + '</li>' + h,a)
                  : h;
}
document.write(result);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.BananaClass {color: orange}
```